# Forward stdout to different tty

Tags: bash, tty

I have an external device, that I can send commands to, and it would respond in a certain way. For this I use two terminals, one sending the commands and one listening to the response. At some point I want to merge these two terminals, but that's not my issue right now.

When I want to send a command to the device, I would use

```
echo foo > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and to listen in the other terminal, I use

```
cat < /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Now I'd like to have a test set up, without me needing the device. I had in mind to have three terminals: Two just as before, and the third one representing the device. The third terminal happens to be `/dev/pts/5`. I can send commands to it

```
echo foo > /dev/pts/5
```

and I can listen on it

```
cat < /dev/pts/5
```

But how can I tell the third terminal to forward all commands that are sent to its `stdout` to a different `tty`? And how could I modify these commands, like when it receives `foo`, it answers `bar`?

Comment: Try `exec 1<&-;exec 1>>/dev/pts/5` and see what happens.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me.